# Unbind C-RET in emacs?

Tags: key-bindings

My finger tends to linger on the Ctrl key and I happen to hit C-RET quite often. I also use cua-mode which binds this to `cua-clear-rectangle-mark`. I don't want C-RET bound to anything while in this mode.

I can't seem to unbind it though. I've tried:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-RET"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "<C-return>"))
(global-unset-key [(control return)])
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-RET") 'ignore)
(define-key global-map (kbd "<C-return>") 'ignore)
(define-key global-map [(control return)] 'ignore)
```

I also tried the following in my .inputrc with no success:

```
"\C-RET": "\n"
```

There also doesn't seem to be a cua-mode-map:

```
;; Doesn't work
(define-key cua-mode-map "C-RET" nil)
```

Comment: `(define-key cua-mode-map (kbd "C-<return>") nil) (define-key cua-mode-map (kbd "C-RET") nil)` ?

Comment: There is no cua-mode-map. At least not in 24.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Emacs 25, if you run `C-h k C-RET` it will tell you that `C-RET` is bound in `cua-global-keymap`, so that's where we unset it

```
(define-key cua-global-keymap [C-return] nil)
```

It seems to be set in the same keymap in 24.4 as well.

Comment: I've loaded emacs with `-q` and don't see cua-global-keymap listed anywhere when invoking `C-h k C-RET` while in cua-mode.

Comment: With `emacs -q` `cua-mode` doesn't get loaded.  Does the keymap exist after you do `M-x cua-mode`?

Comment: I explicitly enable cua-mode after loading emacs with `-q` in this instance. I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough on that.

Comment: @erikstokes The keymap information in `C-h k` was introduced only recently in the dev version of emacs on its git master. Are you building your emacs from git?

Comment: @Zhro The old school method of grepping in emacs source code always works :)

Comment: I'm running the dev version.  However, I also checked 24.4.1 and `C-RET` is bound in `cua-global-keymap` there too.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. This feature was added in June: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=958d20d22a5e9b997de0bf7cc63436dc82486111

Comment: To clarify, `C-h k` isn't giving the keymap in 24.4.  You have to check "by hand" in a non-bleeding-edge Emacs.