# Key binding of a function interferes with global key binding

Tags: key-bindings

The key binding <kbd>\</kbd>  of the function `w3m-show-source` interferes with the function with the same key binding `hydra-master-body` (which I set up in the `init` file). I have used the function `global-set-key` to change the key binding of `w3m-show-source` to <kbd>ctrl-,</kbd>. Now the function `w3m-show-source` has two key bindings <kbd>\</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl-,</kbd>. How can I *remove* <kbd>\</kbd> from the function `w3m-show-source` so that it will execute `hydra-master-body`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unbind C-RET in emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14500/unbind-c-ret-in-emacs)

Comment: in which way should this solve the problem? I tried `(define-key w3m-view-source [\\] nil)
` unsuccessfully.

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: Your `define-key` in your comment is missing a KEYMAP arg. And `[\\]` is not what you want. Did you try `(global-set-key (kbd "\\") nil)`? Or did you try `(global-unset-key (kbd "\\"))`? Your question is unclear/incomplete. We can't answer the question until we know what you're asking and what you've tried.

Comment: `(global-set-key (kbd "\\") nil)`  and   `(global-unset-key (kbd "\\"))` are not working simply because [Unbind C-RET in emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14500/unbind-c-ret-in-emacs) is unrelated to the problem. The  `"\\"`   in `w3m` is interfering with my main hydra command. When I am in w3m and want to call hydra, I get the source of the web page instead. I don't want that,

Answer (score 1):

Find out the solution. The command was `(add-hook 'w3m-mode-hook (lambda () (define-key w3m-mode-map (kbd "\\") nil)))`